# Examples of functions zero on the boundary

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

What are examples of a function $f(x)$ satisfying
$$f(0)=f(l)=f'(0)=f'(l)=0?$$

One example is $f(x)=x^{\beta_1}(l-x)^{\beta_2}$ with $\beta_1, \beta_2>1$.

**Edit** Not of the form $f\cdot g$ or etc.

Comment: Also, $fg$ where $g$ is any continuous function. Is this enough examples?

Comment: Basically, I need functions of form other than $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about some simple trigonometric functions? A possible example is

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{l} \right) - 1,\ n = 0,1,2,\dots
\end{equation}

Comment: Nice, but can one somehow include some parameters in it? In my example there are two parameters $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan, I suppose you could include parameters if you like. What about some other function $g(x) = \beta_1 [f(x)]^{\beta_2}$?

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be some special functions satisfying the condition?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan I'm sure there are, although I cannot think of any ATM.